# Does Shopping cart Rule apply to Simple Associated products also?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a shopping cart price rule to only one category say id 20. Now this category has all the configurable products. The simple products of these configurable products do not have any category assigned.

The rule also applies to the simple products also.

Question: Should the rule be applied to these simple products also? Because they do not have any category assigned?

I use Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

no the special price will only apply to the products that are in the category id:20 even if the parent product is in this category you still have to assign categories for the child products.

hope this help
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Web Bridge. It should be like that. But I have checked this rule with default magento set up with sample data. It was not working as expected.